# Create 3 random names from array to a element

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

God I love this website. So many awesome ppl!

So, I got this far that I can get 1 random name from the array. But now I want 3 different names every time, aaaand I'm stuck -_^

Anyone want to point out my lack of knowledge with their supreme awesomeness? :D
Thanks in advance <3

**The JS**

```
     <script> 

window.onload = funkytown;

function funkytown() {
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = name;
}

function name() {

        var students = ["Mike","Nick","Slagathor","Banana","Rick","Astley","Rock","JW","pronax"];
        var randomize = students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1);

        var html = "Random names: ";

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html + randomize;


     }
     </script>
```

**the HTML**

```
<span id="text"></span>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Randomize!" />
```

Comment: Why do you splice and not just access the array?

Comment: @Kyll - avoids duplicates? - it's like he's prepared for doing it 3 times to get 3 different names

Comment: `but now I want 3 different names every time` ... the functional guts of your function is the `var randomize = ...` line .. do that 3 times somehow to get 3 different names

Comment: Yeah I started but I couldn't figure out what to add and where to add it. Do I add a "while" or something or am I way outside the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to skin this cat

for loop

```
function name() {
    var students = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"];
    var randomize = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        randomize.push(students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1));
    }
    var html = "Tilfeldige navn: ";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html + randomize.join(' ');
}
```

a bit hackish using array.map

```
function name() {
    var students = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"];
    var randomize = [1,2,3].map(function() {
        return students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1);
    }).join(' ');
    var html = "Tilfeldige navn: ";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html + randomize;
}
```

remove random elements until only 3 left

```
function name() {
    var students = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"];
    while(students.length > 3) {
        students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1);
    }
    var html = "Tilfeldige navn: ";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html + students.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! 
I'm learning so much more from SO than from the lectures

Hope the cat's okay though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your existing function that gives you one random name from the array, just call it recursively until you have 3 different names.

```
 var randomNames=[]; 
 var count=0;

function name() {
    if(count==3){
      return;
    }
    var students = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"];
    var randomize = students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1);
    if(randomNames.indexOf(randomize) == -1){
        randomNames.push(randomize );
        ++count;
    }
    name();
  }

 var html = "Tilfeldige navn: ";

 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html + randomNames;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

```
function funkytown() {
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = name;
}

function name() {
    var randomize = [],
        students = ["Hans", "Ole", "Nils", "Olav", "Per", "Knut", "Kari", "Line", "Pia"];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        randomize.push(students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1));
    }

    var html = "Tilfeldige navn: ";

    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html + randomize.join(", ");
}

funkytown();
```

Output:
Tilfeldige navn: Line, Per, Ole

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fuhk4rp/2/) exampe

Comment: Push hasn't been mentioned at all in my course. It's brilliant! Thanks for taking the time dude!